# Enable (CSS) Stylesheet for only one div and it's contents

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-plugins, editor, wysiwyg

I *was* looking for a (simple) WYSIWYG Editor jQuery Plugin that's compatible with Bootstrap 3. I've seen a lot WYSIWYG Editors jQuery Plugin that were compatible with the previous Bootstrap, but my website uses Bootstrap 3, so each time I implemented such a jQuery Plugin, my Bootstrap 3 would ruin the buttons and mess the whole editor up.

So now I'm asking whether there is an option to enable the Bootstrap 2 stylesheet only for one div and its contents.

I assume a iframe could work, but then, I need the WYSIWYG Editor's contents (which are in the iframe then), along with text inputs on the 'non-iframe'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way you might be able to solve this would scope your css for that div. This is what I have implemented with a content management system that I have created.

Let say for example you give the WYSIWYG Div an ID of HTMLEditable.

you could target that div with your css and all the css within that div.

```
#HTMLEditable .WYSIWYG{
   ....css goes here
}

#HTMLEditable p{
   ....css goes here
}
```

The above css will only apply to that div. 
Then its just a case of finding the correct css that you need in that div.

Note you may need to override/reset the css for that div to stop your bootstrap3 applying to it.

[Here](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) is an example of a reset css. (You will need to scope this as well to make sure you don't reset all your css).

EDIT: use LESS

To make this easier you can use LESS which is what bootstrap uses.

```
     #HTMLEditable {
      //import the modal css
       @import "bootstrap.css";
    }
```

you will need to make a file 'HTMLEditable.less'. Then Add the code to similar to the above. 
The less will them compile the above into css and will scope everything in the css to `#HTMLEditable`

Check out the [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) site and look ate the nesting. This is what you are after. This site will also show you how to compile it.

Comment: Thank you, and I know this would work, but the problem is, I just want to include the (minified) stylesheet of Bootstrap 2 for that div. I don't really feel like adding "#HTMLEditable " for every element (unless you know if there's an kind of (online) automated script who does that).

Comment: Added more to the answer. Take a look.

Comment: Thanks, really, but it still doesn't work. Maybe because the bootstrap 2 & 3 javascript files are making a mess together?

Comment: Hmmm. not really sure what to suggest then :/

Comment: Well, I think it will however help other users, and to me it was interesting, so thanks anyway, you deserve question answered.

Comment: No worries. Sorry I could not help more

Answer (score 4):

You need to put the class or id of this div before all css rules. You can do it like this if you need a css file and not less.

```
#HTMLEditable{  
    paste in all of your css
}
```

than copy all of this paste it here: http://less2css.org/ in the less area and it will generate the right css for you.